# cell index to string

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have already tried to get the string of cell, but visual studio 2017 stop me while the program runs.

```
int sumphre = 0;

for (int i =0; i< dataGridViewWhouse.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //here is the problem
    string outString = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[dataGridViewWhouse.SelectedRows[i].Index]
                        .Cells[6]
                        .Value
                        .ToString();

    int length = outString.Length;
    if (length == 4)
    {
        sumphre += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
    }
}

label4.Text = sumphre.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error or exception that you are getting when you run this? From the little information that you provided, we can't really determine what is going wrong. Is it an index out of range issue on the `Cell` or `SelectedRows` collections, or maybe something else? If you can provide the exception there is a much higher chance that your question can be answered.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the exception and stacktrace information?

Comment: the error : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Ο δείκτης βρισκόταν εκτός περιοχής. Η τιμή του δεν πρέπει να είναι αρνητική και πρέπει να είναι μικρότερη από ή ίση με το μέγεθος της συλλογής.
Όνομα παραμέτρου: index'  in line : 
 string outString = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[dataGridViewWhouse.SelectedRows[i].Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

Comment: Are you sure that every row has 6 or 7 cells? It may not find them. I think you must check if they exist and if their value is different from null or whitespace.

Comment: what value you are getting in `dataGridViewWhouse.SelectedRows[i].Index`

Comment: there are 7 cells [id , dateTime , Fname ,Lname , af , Type , move , Quantity]

Comment: if you have 7 cells, the index is 0 to 6

Comment: They may have not always value. You have to check it before assign it to you variables.

Comment: The problem is that selectedRows are < = than all rows. i is getting greater than their number and you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you are getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the following line:

```
string outString = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[dataGridViewWhouse.SelectedRows[i].Index]
                        .Cells[6]
                        .Value
                        .ToString();
```

Further down in your code, you are accessing a row to perform an operation on differently:

```
sumphre += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
```

I question what you are actually trying to do and if you are performing operations on the correct rows. I do not have access to the rest of your code, but I would guess that accessing a row like this `dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[dataGridViewWhouse.SelectedRows[i].Index]` is what is causing the problem. Why are you not getting the row once and use that reference for the whole loop iteration?

```
int sumphre = 0;

for (int i =0; i< dataGridViewWhouse.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i];
    string outString = (row.Cells[6] == null) ? String.Empty : row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    int length = outString.Length;
    if (length == 4)
    {
        sumphre += Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[7] == null) ? "0" : row.Cells[7].Value);
    }
}

label4.Text = sumphre.ToString();
```

If, on the other hand, you need to access the row for that value in this odd way, I need some further information on the design of your application to deduce what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: I need to calculate a sum if the if statement is true. for example i try to calculate a sum if text in cell[6] is "text" the sum += the number in cell[7] but i had the same error in this way i try to calculate the lenght but same error...

Comment: What I am getting at in my answer is that the way you are access your rows, you could be accessing two different rows. I changed that to ensure that the operations are being performed on the same row throughout the loop. You are looping through all of the rows, however in the first call to retrieve the value from cell 6, you are accessing a row in the `SelectedRows` collection. This will throw an error if you don't have all of the rows selected in your table since the total number is always greater than or equal to the number of selected rows.

Comment: var row = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i];
string outString = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();// same error in this line :(

Comment: Which line? You pasted in two lines. Is it the line: `string outString = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();`? In that case, you seem to either not have 6 cells, or that cell contains a null value. I will modify my answer to perform a check. If the table was filled properly though, these extra checks should be unnecessary.

Comment: 36 - 9/5/2019 - test - test  - 02222222 -  BIN - ΠΗΡΕ - 50 //the data of a row

Comment: Are you sure there is only one row? This loop processes every row in that table. It could be any row that throws the exception you are getting.

Comment: There are a lot of rows

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove SelectedRows from Rows. In any other case SelectedRows.Count must be equal to i or you will get the exception.

```
int sumphre = 0;

for (int i =0; i< dataGridViewWhouse.Rows.Count; i++)
{
//here is the problem
string outString = dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i]
                    .Cells[6]
                    .Value
                    .ToString();

int length = outString.Length;
if (length == 4)
{
    sumphre += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewWhouse.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
}
}

label4.Text = sumphre.ToString();
```